# Determining number of callback functions JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Number of callbacks?

In the following code which creates a simple http server, am i correct in saying that this code has **two** callback functions, which are:

1. http.createServer(function(req,res))...
2. server.listen(port, function()..

[image]

Comment: Yes. The first to createServer, the second to listen.

Comment: that said the "callback" is not `http.createServer(function(req,res)).`, the callback is `function(req,res)`, `createServer` is just a normal function call ;)